# установка wordpress в linux mint (ubuntu), Lampp

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress, linux-mint, lampp

Установил  *WP* (*Lampp*), однако столкнулся с проблемой: при попытке установить плагин, *wp* сообщает, что у него нет прав устанавливать файлы в указанные (стандартные) директории.

Как дать ему эти права?

P.S. Возможно я не так понял ситуацию, однако если кто-нибудь сталкивался сподобной проблемой, надеюсь вы ее решили, и вам не сложно поделиться ей здесь.

Comment: [Changing_File_Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) на WP. И не плохо было бы прочитать [Hardening_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions) (не только про права, но все)

Comment: Лично я бы разрешил wp только загрузку картинок, а плагины и прочее напрямую устанавливал бы. Тем более есть [неплохой инструмент](http://wp-cli.org/) для этого:

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, как вы устанавливали *wordpress*.

Comment: через терминал, сначала ламп (msql + apache) потом загрузил ВП)

Comment: а через терминал плагины ставить нельзя? если никак, то в папке wp-content надо разрешить запись (или сделать владельцем www-data) в plugins, themes и uploads (вроде ничего не забыл), тогда сможете устанавливать плагины, загружать медиа-файлы и редактировать тему

Comment: вот это добавьте в wp-config.php в самый низ     
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны права *root* для установки. Попробуйте остановить сервер, а потом запустить командой:

```
sudo <ваша команда для запуска сервера>.
```

Также не забудьте перезапустить потом в обычном режиме.